# Tracking page consultation with Piwik Custom Dimensions

Tags: matomo

I am working with Piwik Custom Dimensions to create a tag system on my platform.
Each user has four tags assigned when added to the users database. The current system allows me to see how many of them visited, how many actions etc.. But I'd like to be able to track, for example, the most visited page for each.

I have seen cases where each tag is expandable in Piwik and is shows additionnal data, but have not found a way to do it.

What should I do and what have I missed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution :

I was using the "**Visit**" scope, which doesn't provide information based on the specific page, only general navigation data.

If you want to be able to see exactly what page was consulted and therefore be able to filter and find the most consulted one, you need to link the data to an "**Action**" dimension, then click the [+] and sort by **visits**.